# Does $C$ diagonal + nonnegative, $ACB^T$ diagonal + nonnegative imply $A =B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $C\in \mathbb R^{m,m}$ is a diagonal nonnegative matrix and $X = ACB^T\in \mathbb R^{n,n}$ is a diagonal nonnegative matrix, does this imply $A = B$? Is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $A=C=I_m$ and $B=diag(1,2,\ldots,m)$.

Comment: Good point. Thanks!

Comment: If $n<m$ you can come up with a similar example.

Answer (score 1):

For almost any $C$ you can find $A\neq B$ satisfying this.

Let
$A$ be a permutation matrix, and $C$ a positive diagonal matrix.  For any positive number $b$ define $B=bA$. Now check that $ACB^T$ is diagonal and positive and 
 so provides plenty of counter examples.